# Are all functions obtained from regular closed sets necessarily continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C$ denote a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the property that for all rays $r$ emanating from the origin, the intersection $r \cap C$ has at least one element. Then there's an associated function $S^1 \rightarrow C$ (where $S^1$ is the unit circle) given by associating to each point of $S^1$ the corresponding ray from the origin and then finding the point of intersection in $S^1$ at a minimum distance to the origin. Unfortunately, this won't usually be continuous; for example, consider $C = \{(x,y) : x^2+y^2 \geq 1\} \cup \{(x,0):x \geq 1/2\}.$ I was wondering if $C$ being regular closed (meaning that its equal to the closure of its interior) is enough.

This seems to be equivalent to the following, more basic question.

> **Question.** Given a regular closed set $C \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $y \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $(x,y) \in C$, is it true that the function $$\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ $$x \mapsto \min\{y \in \mathbb{R} : (x,y) \in C\}$$ is necessarily continuous?

Comment: Such $C$ isn't regular, since $C^{\circ} = \{(x,y) : x^2 + y^2 > 1\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On the function $S^1\to C$:**

Consider the map $t\overset{f}{\mapsto}(t\cos(t),t\sin(t))$ and let 
$$C = \overline{\{p\in\mathbb{R}^2 : \|p\| > \|f(t)\| \; \forall t\in[2\pi,4\pi]\}}.$$
Draw a picture of $C$ and observe that your function $S^1\to C$ has a discontinuity at $(1,0)$.

**About the question:**

This question is simpler, though it is the same idea.
Let $g\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the function $g(x) = \chi_{[0,\infty)}(x)$ and consider
$$C = \overline{\{(x,y) : y > g(x)\;\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\}}.$$
The function $x\mapsto\min\{y\in\mathbb{R} : (x,y)\in C\}$ is just $\chi_{(0,\infty)}$, which is discontinuous at $0$, the same discontinuity of $g$ !

This can be generalized. In fact, $g$ can be, for example, any piecewise continuous function.

Comment: Just for fun, let $g(x) = \tan(x)$ and $g(\pi/2+k\pi) = 0$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, and see what happen.

Comment: A good answer to a stupid question :)